# Why is my Javascript function being skipped?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm just trying to make this simple script to ask the user what they would like to order, but the function is being completely skipped.

```
var foodOrder = function (food) {
    var ask = prompt("What food would you like to order?");

    alert("Okay, "+ask+" coming right up.");

};

var more = prompt("Would you like anything else?");

if (more === "Yes") {
    foodOrder();
}
else
{
    alert("Goodbye");
}
```

Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "skipped"? What happens? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: It is working fine.Check [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/c9jgkLqy/)

Comment: Works fine here: `https://jsfiddle.net/fnnumt9k/`

Comment: `'yes' !== 'Yes' // true` there is no more reason why your function is skipped

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

I think you enter `'yes'` instead of `'Yes'`, that's why the condition is `false`.
Compared it to this:

```
if (more.toLowerCase() === 'yes') { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: So, that's insensitive consoant/vowal check

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```js
var foodOrder = function (food)
{
    var ask = prompt("What food would you like to order?");
    alert("Okay, "+ask+" coming right up.");
};

var more = prompt("Would you like anything else?");

if (more.toLowerCase() === "yes")
{
    foodOrder();
}
else
{
    alert("Goodbye");
}
```